# Create groovy script for run REST request

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I have a task to create groovy script which will run REST request and setup property.
I setup property by script:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "ScriptProFrom", "BIF" )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "ScriptProTo", "STD" )
```

But I can't find how to run REST request. I tried to do it like this:

```
myInterface = (RestService) testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceByName("http://www.webservicex.net")
myOperation = myInterface.getOperationByName("ConversionRate")
myRequest = myOperation.getRequestByName("Request 1")
```

and get `"Script-result: com.eviware.soapui.impl.RestRequest@6a80901"` and it cool if it my request, but how to run it?
Please, help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally if you have a testStep you can get it and then simply run it, however your are doing it in another way so you can use the [submit](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/rest/RestRequest.html#submit%28com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.SubmitContext,%20boolean%29) method of `com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRequest` class. This method has two parameters, the context which is an instance of `com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.SubmitContext` interface and a `boolean` which indicates if the operation is asynchronous. In your code this could be:

```
myInterface = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceByName("http://www.webservicex.net")
myOperation = myInterface.getOperationByName("ConversionRate")
myRequest = myOperation.getRequestByName("Request 1")
// get the context
def context = testRunner.getRunContext()
// send the request synchronous
myRequest.submit(context,false)
```

EDIT BASED ON OP COMMENT:

The submit method returns an object which is instance of [`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit<T>`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlSubmit.html), then you can invoke `getResponse()` on this object an get another object which is instance of [`com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Response`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/iface/Response.html) then from this you can use `getContentAsString()` to check the response content or `getContentType()` to check the content type and so on. Please note that if you invoke submit in asynchronous way you must validate that `getStatus()` returns  `com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Submit.Status.FINISHED` before `getResponse()`. I give you an example:

```
myInterface = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceByName("http://www.webservicex.net")
myOperation = myInterface.getOperationByName("ConversionRate")
myRequest = myOperation.getRequestByName("Request 1")
// get the context
def context = testRunner.getRunContext()
// send the request synchronous
def submitted = myRequest.submit(context,false)
// get the response
def response = submitted.getResponse()
// get the response content as string 
def content = response.getContentAsString()
// i.e check that the response contains literal 'OK'
assert content.contains('OK'),"Response not contains OK literal"
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't understand how to get my xml response with currency rate and make assertion on it, could you help? please...

Comment: I add another example in my answer to give you more help based on your comment. Please if this helps you remember to accept the answer :).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation and sorry for my stupidity but I still have a problem. I run the code you give but without assert and get error:  [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21477424/CurencyRate-soapui-project.xml]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation and sorry for my stupidity but I still have a problem. I run the code you give but without assert and get error:
MultipleCompilationErrorsException:unable to resolve class RestService @ line 1 
Here is xml of my project with test without groovy script and test case with groovy script could you please look on it? Maybe I do mistake at another place. [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21477424/CurencyRate-soapui-project.xml]

If it is easy to do testStep could you give me an example? 
Again sorry for disturb.

Comment: don't worry, ask a question is never stupid :). I'll take a look on your soapui project.

Comment: I check your project, I remove "(RestService)" cast and I correct an error of my code (I use submitted.getContentAsString() but the correct is response.getContentAsString()). Then I run it and works perfect, I get the next result: <double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">0.7319</double>. Update your code with my changes and try it :).