# How to run specified step in SoapUI according testcase result

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have project in soapui with more testcases. After running each testcase I need to run one of two http request, depending on results of steps. So if one or more steps in testcase failed, I need to run httprequest1 and if all steps passed I need to run httprequest2. How can I do this? I have tried many scripts... for now my best solution is something like this, just add groovy script at the end of test case. Problem is that it is checking only last step. I have tried many other solutions, but nothing was working for me. Can somebody help me with this? Thank you

```
def lastResult = testRunner.getResults().last()
def lastResultStatus = lastResult.getStatus().toString()

log.info 'Test  + lastResultStatus

if( lastResultStatus == 'FAILED' )
{

 testRunner.gotoStepByName( 'httprequest1' )
 testRunner.testCase.testSteps["httprequest2"].setDisabled(true)

}
else
{
 testRunner.gotoStepByName( 'httprequest2' )
}
```

another solution that I have tried:

```
for( r in testRunner.results )
result = r.status.toString()
log.info result

if( result == 'FAILED' )
{
testRunner.gotoStepByName( 'httprequest1' )
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["httprequest2"].setDisabled(true)
}
else
{
testRunner.gotoStepByName( 'httprequest2' )
}
```

Comment: Where are the `httpRequest1` and `httpRequest2` test steps located? In same test case or in different case or some where else such different suite? Have you considered running the script as part of test case `Teardown Script` instead of addtional `Groovy Script` step?

Comment: Yes they are in the same test case. If there is some solution for this via Teardown script, I can move it to another test case... But I don't know how to do this with teardown script.

Comment: How about using conditional goto step?

Comment: And what is the issue that you are facing with the script which you posted?

Comment: If I have more steps in test case, it always run httprequest according result of the last step in test case (last before script). So if first 2 steps are failed and third is OK, than it run httprequest2

Comment: Can you please show the test case structure along with the details where to take different transition?

Comment: and about conditional goto... I was thinking about it, but I don't know if its possible to use it for this. How can I set condition when all steps are OK run first or second httprequest?

Comment: This project I have only for testing. Now e.g. first step was failed, next was OK and httprequest 2 was started.
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/cpsev0)

Comment: Please have a look at the answer to see if that helps.

Comment: have you got chance to try the answer?

Comment: Sry I did not have time for this but I will try it today. And I also got advise to try to do it via assertion script, so maybe I will try also something this way...

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned in the comment, and based on the details shared in the comments, `Conditional GoTo` test step can be used. However, it may required multiple of them. Instead `Groovy Script` can be the best way in this scenario.

Here are the details assuming the following are the steps in the test case.

Test Case:

1. request step1
2. request step2
3. groovy script step (the proposed script to handle the scenario)
4. request1 step if above step1 & step2 are successful
5. request2 step otherwise
6. following step x
7. following step y

Here is the pseudo code for the proposed `Groovy Script` mentioned in **#3**.

- Evaluate the previous test step execution result, like what you currently doing.
- Based on the condition, run the test step #4 if true, run step #5 otherwise. Here note that do not use `gotoStepByName` method, instead run step by its name. See sample #15 [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html)
- Once the above `if` ..`else` is done, then use `gotoStepByName` to continue the steps #6, #7 (of course, if any).

NOTE: If `gotoStepByName` is used to run a step in groovy step, then the control will not come back.

Answer (score 0):

Use a testcase teardown to call the step, since you have to do it for all test cases. The teardown script will look something like this:

```
if(testRunner.status.toString() == "FAILED"){
       testRunner.runTestStepByName( "httprequest1")
       println "in if"
}else{
     testRunner.runTestStepByName( "httprequest2")
     println "in else" 
}
```

Note that you have to use the SoapUI Runner to trigger the testcase / suite and the difference in method being called.

Comment: Suggested this in the comment when the details are not available. Later he has shown how the test case structure, and `Teardown Script` does not seem to fit there.

Comment: Actually, his comment begs to differ. In his words "But I don't know how to do this with teardown script.". Also, in his code, OP is trying to do it at the test step level, plus his solution isnt working for him. I did see your suggestion but it didnt have the solution. The other aspect is the trigger - He cannot have the teardown script triggered unless he is executing using the SOAPUI runner.

Comment: "I did see your suggestion but it didnt have the solution"- What do you mean? Given the approach how to do along with pseudo instructions, just needs to add the statements.

Comment: The main issue in OP's code is goto "Step". That is not going to work because a goto will continue to run the next steps as well. Whereas the requirement is to just run some steps, so he doesnt need to use "goto" but  "run". I understand that you gave him pseudo code but the comment didnt suggest the change from Goto to Run. That could have confused him. If this doesnt convince you I can delete the prev comment and reword it.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate help from both of you. I will read it carefully and try to do it somhow today. But as for Teardown script. It is executed at the end after my testcase was finished if I am right, so my httprequest step will be also executed before script, if it is in the same testcase right?

Comment: Yes it will. There are two ways to handle that. The easier way:Your teststep will be disabled by default and will be enabled in the teardown script or 
use api to create the requests in the teardown. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477885/create-groovy-script-for-run-rest-request

Comment: Or maybe I can just add as the last step groovy script, that will enable this steps. But I have tried now that teardown script, but it is not working for me. Where is the problem?
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/cq0dok)

Comment: Thats why I explicitly mentioned the SoapUI Runner :) . Right click on the test case and select Launch TestRunner. Select the testcase in the Launch TestRunner window and execute.